# What is this white space called and how to access it

Tags: css, web, mobile

I am making a web-page geared for mobile view but I notice there is this white space at the top of the page on my iphone when viewing it online.
I am using safari on iPhone. I will attach a picture below with the white space in question circled.
it's the white space at the very top of the iphone where details such as the clock, battery power, and signal strength are located.
I want to be able to change the color of this space.

one of the pages in question]

[image: 1]

Here is some relevant css code that I am using

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(./images/wei-zeng-WsgNGq1aqIQ-unsplash.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a meta tag for `theme-color` containing the color you want it to be.

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#FFF">
```

https://css-tricks.com/meta-theme-color-and-trickery/

> According to tests I made earlier this year, this works in Chrome, Brave and Samsung Internet on Android, installed PWAs in Chrome and now also in Safari Technology Preview.

[image]